# Not able to save changes made to html table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I created this table to take place of the access database we are using now, I am going to link it to our home page once it is complete. This is just the caption, title row and first row of our gauge list. I can't seem to save the data I put in. Is it set up to save with another button?
I can double click the cell to input data and press enter but when I refresh the page the data is gone, not saved?
What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(function () {
    $("td").dblclick(function () {
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();


        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
        $(this).children().first().focus();
 
        $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var newContent = $(this).val();
                $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
            }
        });
  
    $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");


    });
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    font-family:arial;
}

 
.editableTable {
    border:1px solid white;
    width:100%
}
 
.editableTable td {
    border:1px solid white;
}
 
.editableTable .cellEditing {
    padding: 5px;
}
 
.editableTable .cellEditing input[type=text]{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:rgb(255,253,210);  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Active Calibrations</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<style>
body {
   background-color: #002255;
}
table {
    width:100%;
    font-family: arial;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
caption{
    display: table-caption;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: stencil;
    font-size: 300%;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #888888;
    color: white;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #002255;
    color: white;
}
table#t01 th {
    background-color: #888888;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="t01" style="width:100%"
table class="editableTable">
  <caption>ACTIVE CALIBRATIONS</caption>
<br>
<thead>
<removeClass("cellEditing");
 <tr>
    <th>PLANT</th>
    <th>TYPE</th>
    <th>Serial#</th>
    <th>LAST CAL</th>
    <th>CAL DUE</th>
    <th>LOCKER</th>
    <th>MODEL</th>
    <th>FREQ</th>
    <th>RESPON</th>
    <th>IN/OUT</th>
    <th>REMARKS</th>
    <th>RANGE</th>
    <th>P-CAL</th>
    <th>SECTION</th>
    <th>MANUFACTURER</th>
    <th>COST CAL</th>
    <th>EQUIP COST</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td>Blanket</td>
    <td>Gauge Block 1 mm</td>
    <td>04061</td>
    <td>8/27/15</td>
    <td>8/27/17</td>
    <td>Lab</td>
    <td>Mitutoyo 614519-03</td>
    <td>2 YRS</td>
    <td></td> 
    <td>Out</td>
    <td>Put in Service</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>$7.50</td>
    <td>$25.00</td>
 </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which part of your code do you think should save your data within a database?

Comment: I guess update would be a better word than save. I didn't plan on saving to a database. I was trying to eliminate the access database we are using now.

Comment: Is there not a way of saving with out a database? How do I set it up

Comment: The correct way is making use of databases! As javascript is executed client side, the only possible way to store something is making use of cookie.

Comment: Also, cookies & local storage wouldn't make any changes available to people not using that machine. If you want everyone to be able to see changes to data, you need a database.

Comment: As of right now a server holds all files with intranet and that is where this will be